# Add textview in actionbar - android

Tags: android

I want to show a text in the right top corner of the actionbar. i have added the textview to the action bar using the following layout.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="#00000000"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:gravity="right"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/balance_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="test balance"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

and in the activity as

```
    LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_layout, null);
    ((LinearLayout) v).setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

    actionBar.setCustomView(v);
```

It works perfectly. But it adds text in the center of the action bar. I want the text to be placed in right. I tried with gravity as well. But nothing works.

Any suggestions.

Comment: set `mActionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);` and `mActionbar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);` for your `Actionbar`.

Comment: If the textView is only component you need in actionBar then why don't you create a LinearLayout with only textView at put it at the top?

Answer (score 5):

First step, you must create a layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:background="@drawable/black_pattern" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate" />
```

In onCreate:

```
    ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
    TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
    mTitleTextView.setText("My Own Title");

    ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) mCustomView
            .findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Refresh Clicked!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

Comment: In that blog, they designed for total action bar. i just want to add textview in the right side. I dont to want to put again logo and title in the XML.

Comment: When you put textView in ActionBar you must add everything because textView will never be in center.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your LinearLayout by a RelativeLayout and set property android:layout_alignParentRight to true in your TextView.

That should do it works.

Comment: I tried that too. But when using relative layout, actionbar title got hidden.

Answer (score -3):

the following codes worked for me! Hope it will work for u too!!
In your Edit text property add this line

"android:layout_gravity="center"